# React, custom word list spell check for a textarea?

Tags: reactjs, spell-checking

How can I spell check a textarea from a custom wordlist, and add red squiggly line under the wrong words.

(`<textarea spellCheck="true" />` doesn't help.)

Answer (score 0):

The spell check will come from operating system the attribute you have used is correct just add language attribute `lang` for it

Code :

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState("Helo world");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Text Area Spell Check</h1>
      <textarea
        value={val}
        onChange={(e) => setVal(e.target.value)}
        spellCheck={true}
        lang={"en"}
      ></textarea>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Check it in codesandbox

[image: Edit affectionate-khayyam-y2x8ko]